# Preload a Scene to prevent lag?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Hello guys i have made the first Level of my game, but always when i go from the main menu screen to the first level the screen freezes for like 2 Seconds and the transition from the Main screen to the game is very delayed and laggy and it sometimes doesn't even show up. Is there a way to preload the Scene in the background to prevent the lag?

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like, but what I would do is begin rendering it in the background once the main menu screen is loaded, then just remove the main menu. Render it sort of like a 2D object in your world. What you -should- do is provide a MCVE sample of your code in these cases.

Comment: And how can i render it in the background?

Comment: And also what means MCVE? :D

Comment: I don't know what library you're using, but for C++ & DirectX 11, you render the main menu as a 2D object, place it in a way that the camera is looking onto it (so that it's covering it's entire view, then just begin rendering the background.) As soon as they click "Start", you delete the menu object from the field.

Comment: I use Sprite kit with Swift in Xcode

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) 

That shouldn't make too big of a difference. Just render the main menu as an entity.

Comment: I've never notice something like that with spritekit. But without any more information or code, it is impossible to help you more. How many nodes in your scene? Which kind? etc.

Comment: dang its too long to post it

Comment: about 60-70 spriteNodes

Comment: and a few sound effects

Comment: @DarmaniLink i don't know how to do that, thats why i made this post

Comment: How are you rendering the sprites? You render the menu on a top layer, then render everything else behind it, followed by 'clearing' the menu, unless everything's rendered per frame. In that case, I don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can load the resources for the scene in a different thread.  I do this in my game to get really snappy scene transitions despite the fact im loading tons of resources.

**make a static function in your scene class to preload your scene**

```
class func createResources(withCompletion: (scene: BaseScene) -> ()){

    // load resources on other thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {

        let scene = YourScene()

        // callback on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            // Call the completion handler back on the main queue.
            withCompletion(scene: scene)
        });
    })

}
```

**call it like this**

```
    YourScene.createResources(withCompletion: {
        [weak self]
        scene in

        self!.skView.presentScene(scene)
    })
```

So the way to use this is to build your scene in advance on the different thread.  since its running on a different thread you shouldnt get that awkward pause.

for example.  lets say the player reaches the goal of beating the level.  before I was using this method the game would pause for a second before loading the next scene.

When the player beats the level now I still allow them to move around until the next scene has loaded and then the player will instantly shoot into the next level creating an instant transition.

you can see it here when the ship is hyperspacing between levels.  there are a lot of resources loading but the transitions are seamless.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_bXA3woOmo

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 version of @hamobi answer

file: **DispatchQueueExtensions.swift**

```
import Foundation

extension DispatchQueue {

    static func background(_ task: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            task()
        }
    }

    static func main(_ task: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            task()
        }
    }
}
```

file: **GameScene.swift**

```
extension GameScene {
    class func create(completion: @escaping (_ scene: GameScene) -> Void) {        
        DispatchQueue.background {
            let scene = GameScene()
            DispatchQueue.main {
               completion(scene)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
GameScene.create(completion: { [weak self] scene in

            let transition = SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: 1.0)
            self?.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
})
```