# Slow Skscene transition

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, xcode7

I have two scenes: Home and Play. The transition to play scene is really slow compared to the transition to home scene. I think this is because there's more happing in my play scene. Is there any way I can preload play scene ? Or make the transition more seamless?

I'm interested in the answer in this forum [Preload a Scene to prevent lag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990795/preload-a-scene-to-prevent-lag)
but I have no idea where to begin. Where do I place part A and B of the answer

Here is what I'm using

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches
    let location = touch.first!.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

    if (node.name == "Balloon") {

        let sceneAction = SKAction.runBlock({
            let secondScene = Scene2(size: self.size)
            let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(1)
            secondScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
            self.scene!.view?.presentScene(secondScene, transition: transition)
        })
            PlayButton.runAction(SKAction.sequence([sound,SKAction.animateWithTextures(array, timePerFrame: 0.1),sceneAction,SKAction.waitForDuration(1)]))


    }
```

Any other solution is fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I do this and works:
in **didView** of **HomeScene** put `preloadGameScene()`
And always in home scene:

```
fileprivate var nextScene: SKScene?

func preloadGameScene () {
    let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
        self.nextScene = GameScene(fileNamed:"yoursksfilename")
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            print("SCENE LOADED")
            let loading = self.childNodeWithName("Loading") as? SKLabelNode
            self.playButton?.hidden = false
            self.playButton?.alpha = 0
            //loading?.hidden = true
            self.playButton?.runAction(SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(1.0, duration: 0.4))
            loading!.runAction(SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0.0, duration: 0.4))
        })

    })
}
```

`goToGameScene()` is called by a button personal SKButton class:

```
    func goToGameScene () {
        guard let nextScene = nextScene else {return}
        let transition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.5)
        nextScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene!.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
    }
```

**UPDATE SWIFT 3**

```
fileprivate var nextScene: SKScene?

func preloadGameScene () {
        let qualityOfServiceClass = DispatchQoS.QoSClass.background
        let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: qualityOfServiceClass)
        backgroundQueue.async(execute: {
            self.nextScene = GameScene(fileNamed:"yoursksfilename")
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                print("SCENE LOADED")
                let loading = self.childNode(withName: "Loading") as? SKLabelNode
                self.playButton?.isHidden = false
                self.playButton?.alpha = 0
                //loading?.hidden = true
                self.playButton?.run(SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 1.0, duration: 0.4))
                loading?.run(SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0.0, duration: 0.4))
            })

        })
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I tried this for swift 3 and it doesnt work. Can you please update your answer ?

Comment: It gives me an error  "Gameconfiguration does not has no member Level ".

Comment: @Yraw sure, that is my gamescene, gameConfiguration level is my struct with name of level, put your gamescene as in gameviewcontroller with your scene name, maybe is GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")